# Give special permissions to groups about a specific directory

Tags: server, permissions

I have Ubuntu server 16.04.3 installed, then I have 3 directories: /group1 , /group2 , /everyone .

Now I already have groups named group1 and group2 and want users in the group1 and group2 groups to be the only ones who can write to their respective directories. ***Anyone should be able to write to the /everyone directory, but they should not be able to delete files belonging to other users.***

After searching the site, I used `sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx /group1`to set permissions for /group1 & /group2.

How do I set permissions to /everyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what sticky bit is for, look at `/tmp`.

You can do:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /everyone
```

Now, everyone can write to `/everyone`, but only owners will be able to remove/modify/rename their files. Obviously the directory `owner:group` can perform actions based on the permission assigned to them, which in this case, is *anything*. Go for something restrictive for them if you want more control over their permissions.